# Wamp (Apache) redirects calls on subdirectory php files to parent directory

Tags: php, redirect, wamp

On a local dev machine running Wamp, I get strange behaviors.

- When I call from an ajax call my `/phplib/login.php` page, Wamp
  (apache) redirect it to `/login.php`.
- The result is the same when I call this /phplib/login.php page
  directly from my browser.
- For information I don't use any .htaccess file.
- The same code running on a Centos machine with apache (site located
  in `/var/www/html`) works fine.

I've searched for hours now but can't find reason. Thanks for your help.

Comment: With the backslash at the beginning of `/phplib/login.php` it say go t the root folder so try removing the leading backslash to make the folder a relative reference.

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes for this:

- You have a rewrite rule in the server somewhere (.httpd-conf, vhosts configuration etc) that is rewriting the url
- There is a file `root_directory/phplib/login.php` that is itself redirecting to `root_directory/login.php`
- You are unknowingly changing the form's action to `/login.php` via some javascript written long ago or similar
- You have an application-level route that redirects `/phplib/login.php` to `/login.php`

How to debug

1. Terminate PHP execution on the first line in `/phplib/login.php`
2. Use a decent webdev tool and make sure the request is sent to `/phplib/login.php` initially.
3. See what the server response code is.

If the request is not sent at the right url initially, this means that your client side is messing up the request path.
If The server responds with a 3xx code, this means that your server configuration is rewriting the url from somewhere.
If you get a blank screen with response code 200, this means your script has been called and exited on the first line, which would mean your application is redirecting.